# Python Hangman Problem (Line 12: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

```
guess_amount = 0
word = "application"
guesses = []

def make_a_guess():
    user_guess = input("Type your guess: ")
    if user_guess in word: 
        guesses.append(user_guess)

        print("Nice, make another guess!")
    elif user_guess not in word:
        guess_amount += 1


while guess_amount < 5:
    make_a_guess()
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guesses:
            print(letter, end='')
        else:
            print("_", end='')
```

Whenever I run this program, this error comes up and I don't know how to fix it: (Line 12: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment). Im not done with the game, but I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare `guess_amount` as global if you want to modify it:

```
def make_a_guess():
    global guess_amount
    # ...
```